# Finding the longest section in a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a file that begins with SUBBEGIN and ends with SUBEND but have many lines in between these two.
I want to fetch any such section that has maximum number of lines in between SUBBEGIN and SUBEND. It will be helpful for me, if I get a command as well for this filtering. a one liner command along with a script for future use.

```
<SUBBEGIN
        IMSI=XXXXXXXX;
        MSISDN=XXXXXXXXXXXX;
        DEFCALL=TS11;
        CURRENTNAM=BOTH;
        CAT=COMMON;
        TBS=TS11&TS12&TS21&TS22&TS61&BS26&BS2G;
        ODBIC=BAIC;
        ODBOC=BAOC;
<SUBEND
<SUBBEGIN
        IMSI=XXXXXXXX;
        MSISDN=XXXXXXXXXXXX;
        DEFCALL=TS11;
        CURRENTNAM=BOTH;
<SUBEND
```

Desired is like below

```
<SUBBEGIN
        IMSI=XXXXXXXX;
        MSISDN=XXXXXXXXXXXX;
        DEFCALL=TS11;
        CURRENTNAM=BOTH;
        CAT=COMMON;
        TBS=TS11&TS12&TS21&TS22&TS61&BS26&BS2G;
        ODBIC=BAIC;
        ODBOC=BAOC;
<SUBEND
```

Please suggest !!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133932/discussion-on-question-by-surya-shukla-linux-using-grep-function).

Comment: Can you have multiple blocks that are the same max length? If so should 1 of them (which one?) be output or all of them or something else? Please [edit] your question to provide the answer.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `awk`:

```
gawk -v 'RS=<SUBEND\n' -v ORS= -F'\n' '
  NF > max {max = NF; ret = $0 RT}
  END      {if (max) print ret}'
```

Here we set `<SUBEND`newline as the `R`ecord `S`eparator. So the records will run from one `<SUBEND\n` to the next, which on your sample input does match `<SUBBEGIN...<SUBEND` records. If there may be something else in between those `<SUBBEGIN...<SUBEND` records or if there may not be a newline between one record's `<SUBEND` and the next record's `<SUBBEGIN`, the method would have to be adapted.

For instance with:

```
gawk -v 'RS=<SUBEND' -F'\n' '
  !(RT && sub(/.*<SUBBEGIN/, "<SUBBEGIN")) {next}
  NF > max {max = NF; ret = $0 RT}
  END      {if (max) print ret}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this as a starting point:

```
awk '
/<SUBBEGIN/     {NRBEGIN   = NR
                 IMSIFOUND = 0
                }
/<SUBEND/       {if (IMSIFOUND) {DELTA = NR - NRBEGIN
                                 if (DELTA > DLMX)      {DLMX = DELTA
                                                         NRMX = NRBEGIN
                                                        }
                                }
                }
/IMSI/          {IMSIFOUND = 1
                }
END             {print NRMX ",+" DLMX "p"
                }
' file |  sed -nf- file
        IMSI=XXXXXXXX;
        MSISDN=XXXXXXXXXXXX;
        DEFCALL=TS11;
        CURRENTNAM=BOTH;
        CAT=COMMON;
        TBS=TS11&TS12&TS21&TS22&TS61&BS26&BS2G;
        ODBIC=BAIC;
        ODBOC=BAOC;
<SUBEND
```

It records the starting, and ending line numbers for the largest block IF "IMSI" was found in between, and in the `END` section prints out a small `sed` script that prints out the respective lines.

If you don't want to run through your LARGE file twice, with two different commands, try

```
awk '
/<SUBBEGIN/     {delete WIP
                 CNT = IMSIFOUND = 0
                }
                {WIP[++CNT] = $0
                }
/<SUBEND/       {if (IMSIFOUND) {if (CNT > MAX) {for (i=1; i<=CNT; i++) BLOCK[i] = WIP[i]
                                                 MAX   = CNT
                                                }
                                }
                }
/IMSI/          {IMSIFOUND = 1
                }
END             {for (i=1; i<=MAX; i++) print BLOCK[i]
                }
' file5
<SUBBEGIN
        IMSI=XXXXXXXX;
        MSISDN=XXXXXXXXXXXX;
        DEFCALL=TS11;
        CURRENTNAM=BOTH;
        CAT=COMMON;
        TBS=TS11&TS12&TS21&TS22&TS61&BS26&BS2G;
        ODBIC=BAIC;
        ODBOC=BAOC;
<SUBEND
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```bsh
awk '
  {lines[NR]=$0}
  $0 == "<SUBBEGIN" {start=NR}
  $0 == "<SUBEND" && (NR-start) > subsize {substart=start; subsize=(NR-start)} 
  END{for (i=substart; i<=(substart+subsize);i++) print lines[i]}
' file
```

- `{lines[NR]=$0}` - save all lines to array
- `$0 == "<SUBBEGIN" {start=NR}` save line number on "sub" start
- `$0 == "<SUBEND" && (NR-start) > subsize {substart=start; subsize=(NR-start)}` when "sub" ends and is the longest "sub" so far, save  `substart` and `subsize` variables.
- `END{for (i=substart; i<=(substart+subsize);i++) print lines[i]}` - From the saved array, print `subsize` lines, starting from `substart`

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk without buffering the whole file and assuming there is no interior sections within each section:

```
awk '!/^<SUBEND$/{ buf= (buf==""?"": buf ORS) $0; c++; next } 
     c>max       { maxBlk=buf ORS $0; buf=""; max=c } { c=0 }
END{ print maxBlk }' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

Can do with range operator (...) to select the desired block:

```
perl -ne '
  next unless my $e = /^<SUBBEGIN$/ ... /^<SUBEND$/;
  push @A, $_;
  next unless $e =~ /E0/;
  @A > @B and @B = @A;
  $#A=-1;
  }{print @B;
' file
```

---

Using Perl in slurp mode (-0777) so that the file gets treated as one long string on which we can use regex to extract sections:

```
perl -lp -0777 -e '
  my($rec,$max) = ($_);
  $_ = "";
  while ($rec =~ /^<SUBBEGIN\n(?:.*?\n)?<SUBEND$/msg ) {
    my $a = $& =~ tr/\n//;
    $a > $max and ($max,$_) = ($a,$&);
  }
' file
```

---

Using `awk` with its range operator (,):

```
awk '
/^<SUBBEGIN$/,/^<SUBEND$/{
  bufSize++
  buf = buf $0 ORS
  if (/^<SUBEND$/) {
    if (bufSize > max) {
      max = bufSize
      maxbuf = buf
    }
    buf = ""
    bufSize = 0
  }
}
END { printf "%s", maxbuf }
' file
```

---

Using **Python** with its **itertools** module and **groupby** method:

```
python3 -c 'import sys, itertools as it
blkB,blkE = "<SUBBEGIN\n","<SUBEND\n"
g = lambda x: x == blkE
prev = []
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:   
  for k,igrp in it.groupby(f,g):
    G = list(igrp)
    if not k:
      try: idx = G.index(blkB)
      except ValueError: continue
      ll = len(G) - idx
      if ll > len(prev): prev = G[idx:]
  if len(prev):print(*prev,blkB,sep="",end="")
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `sed` , here shown with GNU sed in extended regex mode (-E)

```
B='<SUBBEGIN'
E='<SUBEND'

sed -E "/\n/q
  /^$B\$/!d
  s/^/\n/
  :loop
    N;s/^/_/
  /\n$E\$/!bloop
  G;ta;:a
  /^(_+)(\n$B\n).*\n\1_+\2/!s/(\n$E)\n.*/\1/
  tupdt
  g;:updt
  h;\$D;d
" file
```

The scheme is as follows:

- for every line read place an underscore in the beginning.
- we will compare the lengths of leading underscores just behind the block begin.
- accumulate the block in the pattern space.
- stick the hold onto pattern space.
- only when the pattern space block underscores are lengthier or same than hold do we store new block in hold.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -e 'my @a; my $top = rx/^ \<SUBBEGIN $/; my $bot = rx/^ \<SUBEND $/; \
   for lines() {@a.push: %( m/<$top>/fff/<$bot>/ => $_) if m/<$top>/fff/<$bot>/ }; \
   my $maxpair1 = @a>>.keys>>.Int.maxpairs.List; $_.values.put for \
   @a[(1 + $maxpair1[0].keys.[0] - $maxpair1[0].value.[0]) ... $maxpair1[0].keys.[0] ];' file
```

OR

```perl
raku -e 'my @a; my $top = rx/^ \<SUBBEGIN $/; my $bot = rx/^ \<SUBEND $/; \
   for lines() { if m/<$top>/fff/<$bot>/ -> $n {@a.push: \%($n => $_) };}; \
   my $maxpair1 = @a>>.keys>>.Int.maxpairs.List; $_.values.put for \
   @a[(1 + $maxpair1[0].keys.[0] - $maxpair1[0].value.[0]) ... $maxpair1[0].keys.[0] ];' file
```

Sample Input:

```
garbage1
<SUBBEGIN
        IMSI=XXXXXXXX;
        MSISDN=XXXXXXXXXXXX;
        DEFCALL=TS11;
        CURRENTNAM=BOTH;
        CAT=COMMON;
        TBS=TS11&TS12&TS21&TS22&TS61&BS26&BS2G;
        ODBIC=BAIC;
        ODBOC=BAOC;
<SUBEND
garbage2
<SUBBEGIN
        IMSI=XXXXXXXX;
        MSISDN=XXXXXXXXXXXX;
        DEFCALL=TS11;
        CURRENTNAM=BOTH;
<SUBEND
```

Sample Output:

```
<SUBBEGIN
        IMSI=XXXXXXXX;
        MSISDN=XXXXXXXXXXXX;
        DEFCALL=TS11;
        CURRENTNAM=BOTH;
        CAT=COMMON;
        TBS=TS11&TS12&TS21&TS22&TS61&BS26&BS2G;
        ODBIC=BAIC;
        ODBOC=BAOC;
<SUBEND
```

Above is a solution coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. The code relies on a few niceties of the Raku language, including Raku's `fff` sed-like "flip-flop" operator, which selects text based upon two regex matchers. When called (presumably) in scalar context, the `m/<$top>/fff/<$bot>/` flip-flop will return an index, like so (using Sample Input):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

The Raku's `maxpairs` function will return one-or-more `pairs` indicating the location of `max`-imum values, like so (`maxpairs` of preceding number sequence).

```
(9 => 10)
```

The key is position `9` and the value is `10`. Once the `key` (index position) and `value`(number of lines) of the largest section(s) are both known, it's simple enough to obtain the index position of first line of that section, via subtraction.

Finally, if multiple sections all have the same (maximal) length, the code above is hardcoded to return the first `max` section, using `$maxpair1[0]`. To return the second `max` section, change all instances of `$maxpair1[0]` to `$maxpair1[1]`. To return the last `max` section, change all instances to `$maxpair1[*-1]`. (And looping through the `$maxpairs1` scalar is easy enough to do, if you desire all `max` sections returned).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41555548/7270649
https://raku.org